# Python how to convert a string (containing enter) to a list without ascii characters

Tags: python, string, list, ascii

I am trying to get the output of a tool and making a list out of the output. I have managed to get a propper list using regex, but it is not really a list but a string.
I have tried using `splitlines()` and `split()` to transform it into a propper list but I can't seem to do it.

This is (a part of) the string that needs to be converted to a list:

```
www.nu.nl
2017.nu.nl
account.nu.nl
accounts.nu.nl
actie.nu.nl
admin.nu.nl
admin-2.nu.nl
admin-2-public.nu.nl
adverteren.nu.nl
www.adverteren.nu.nl
privacy.adverteren.nu.nl
advertorial.nu.nl
api.nu.nl
api2.nu.nl
autodiscover.nu.nl
beta.nu.nl
privacy.beta.nu.nl
brandedcontent.nu.nl
cdn.nu.nl
cmp.nu.nl
editorialinsights.nu.nl
f1.nu.nl
f1spel.nu.nl
facebook.nu.nl
foto.nu.nl
```

When I use the split() or splitlines() I get the following output:

```
['\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92m2017.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92maccount.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92maccounts.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mactie.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madmin.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madmin-2.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madmin-2-public.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.adverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.adverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madvertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi2.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mautodiscover.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mbeta.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.beta.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mbrandedcontent.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mcdn.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mcmp.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92meditorialinsights.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mf1.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mf1spel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mfacebook.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mfoto.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mgadgets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mgraph.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mi.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92miphone.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlink.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlive.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlogin.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlogin2.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mm.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.m.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmedia.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmedia-staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmediatoolui.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmeedoen.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmessagent.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmetrics.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmijnomgeving.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmijnomgeving-acc.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmijnteam.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.mijnteam.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmobi.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmobiel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.mobiel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmsoid.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mnewsquiz.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.nu.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mnumobileapp.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mold.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92morange.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mpreview.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msecure.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msentry.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mservice.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mshop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.shop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msimonly-advertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.simonly-advertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msip.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mspecials.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstaging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi.staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk-cdn.staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstaging-shop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstatic.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstories.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk-cdn.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtest.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi-cms2test.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk-cdn.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk2022-cdn.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww-cms2test.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww1.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtest-shop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtest-voordeel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtools.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtourtopper.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92murl8180.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mverkiezingen.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mvoordeel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwidgets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92macceptatie.widgets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwintickets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.wintickets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.www.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww1.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mzon.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mbrandedcontent.oudersvannu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmedia.oudersvannu.nl\x1b[0m']
```

I figured it were ascii characters and I have tried to filter them out using the

```
.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

and then `.decode()` method, but that makes no difference.

**My code:**

```
pattern = '(?<=Total Unique Subdomains Found: ..)(?s)(.*$)'
result = subprocess.run(['python3', '/opt/sublist3r/sublist3r.py', '-d', self.domain], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8')
regexOutput = re.findall(pattern, result)

print(regexOutput[0]))
```

This gives me the list that is at the beginning of this post.

Could anyone help me on what to do?

Comment: We will need a [mre] actually containing those characters... Did you try `split('\n')`?

Comment: Also this could be an XY problem. i.e. you're asking about what you think is a solution for another problem, instead of asking about that problem in the first place. In other words, can you parse the source in a way that will yield each row separately?

Comment: These are escape sequences for coloring console output, so `\x1b[92m` would be light green and `\x1b[0m` turns all attributes off meaning in this case not green anymore.

Comment: split('\n') gives me about the same result except that this -> [0m', ''] is placed at the end of the list that I got.

Comment: @Mushroomator How would I delete those or get them out of my list?

Answer (score 0):

These are escape sequences to be able to print in color to e.g `bash`.
`\x1b[92` means light green and `\x1b[0m` means turn everything off i. e. stop writing in green.

FYI: Here a nice [list](https://gist.github.com/raghav4/48716264a0f426cf95e4342c21ada8e7) of such escape sequences and their meaning.

One very simple way you could get rid of them is the following.

> I am sure there are better ways to do this e.g with regex.

```py
domain_list = ['\x1b[92mprivacy.adverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madvertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92m2017.nu.nl\x1b[0m']

for domain in domain_list:
    print("Before:", domain)
    domain = domain.replace("\x1b[92m", "")
    domain = domain.replace("\x1b[0m", "")
    print("After:", domain)
```

Here a screenshot of what it looks like in the console before and after:
[image]

Comment: When I use this I get this as ouptut: ['\nwww.nu.nl\n2017.nu.nl\naccount.nu.nl\naccounts.nu.nl\nactie.nu.nl\nadmin.nu.nl\nadmin-2.nu.nl\......] Making the list into a string and then replacing the '\n\ with '',' " and then back into a list does not seem the way that I should go right?

Comment: You should first use `split()` or `splitlines()` like you described in your post at the beginning and then iterate over that list and apply this. This should work. The `domain_list` in my example is just a list with a few values from the list you have provided in your blog post. You can see that the list you have provided contains the desired values except that they are separated by a `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to delete them:

```
import re
ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
a = ['\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92m2017.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92maccount.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92maccounts.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mactie.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madmin.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madmin-2.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madmin-2-public.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.adverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.adverteren.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92madvertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi2.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mautodiscover.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mbeta.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.beta.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mbrandedcontent.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mcdn.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mcmp.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92meditorialinsights.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mf1.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mf1spel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mfacebook.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mfoto.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mgadgets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mgraph.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mi.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92miphone.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlink.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlive.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlogin.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mlogin2.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mm.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.m.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmedia.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmedia-staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmediatoolui.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmeedoen.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmessagent.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmetrics.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmijnomgeving.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmijnomgeving-acc.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmijnteam.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.mijnteam.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmobi.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmobiel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.mobiel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmsoid.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mnewsquiz.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.nu.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mnumobileapp.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mold.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92morange.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mpreview.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msecure.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msentry.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mservice.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mshop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.shop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msimonly-advertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.simonly-advertorial.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92msip.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mspecials.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstaging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi.staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk-cdn.staging.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstaging-shop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstatic.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mstories.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk-cdn.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtest.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mapi-cms2test.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk-cdn.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtalk2022-cdn.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww-cms2test.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww1.test.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtest-shop.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtest-voordeel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtools.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mtourtopper.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92murl8180.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mverkiezingen.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mvoordeel.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwidgets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92macceptatie.widgets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwintickets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.wintickets.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mprivacy.www.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mwww1.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mzon.nu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mbrandedcontent.oudersvannu.nl\x1b[0m', '\x1b[92mmedia.oudersvannu.nl\x1b[0m']
ansi_escape = re.compile(r'\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])')
print([ansi_escape.sub('', i) for i in a])
```

Comment: When I use this I get this as ouptut: ['\nwww.nu.nl\n2017.nu.nl\naccount.nu.nl\naccounts.nu.nl\nactie.nu.nl\nadmin.nu.nl\nadmin-2.nu.nl\......] Making the list into a string and then replacing the '\n\ with '',' " and then back into a list does not seem the way that I should go right?